# PFQuery - How to get NSError?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Parse API for get and find methods have signature returning object(s) and NSError but signature that i see in XCode returns Error and not NSError.
Pls see some examples.

```
 let userQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery?.getObjectInBackground(withId: <#T##String#>, block: { (<#PFObject?#>, <#Error?#>) in
        <#code#>
    })

PFUser.current()?.fetchInBackground(block: { (<#PFObject?#>, <#Error?#>) in
            <#code#>
        })

PFQuery().findObjectsInBackground { (<#[PFObject]?#>, <#Error?#>) in
            <#code#>
        }
```

Due to this i am able to find out the error code.

Why so? i am using Parse iOS SDK 1.15.4.

Thanks

Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSError` conforms to the `Error` protocol so just bridge cast the type

```
let nsError = error as NSError
let errorCode = nsError.code
```

Comment: it is working. Will accept it.  i was trying to cast it to NSError within result block and it was giving error. Thanks.

Comment: The explanation is a bit misleading. If `A` conforms to `B` then you can cast `A` to `B`, but not the other way around. – `Error` to `NSError` bridging is (I think) treated special, like `String` to `NSString`).